# Please create [apphub]

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I just asked [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89034/change-owner-of-app-in-apphub) about [AppHub](https://apphub.io/), but don't have enough rep to tag it correctly. Could somebody with sufficient rep fix it for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[apphub](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apphub) has been created. It could use a wiki and an excerpt, especially guidance for what questions are okay for Web Apps and what questions should be posted to Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Done](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68552) and [done](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68551), although since I'm a newbie here I'm not 100% certain the advice I'm giving is appropriate.

Comment: ...and, it's gone. Because the one question with the tag got no answers, votes, and very few views, and so was automatically deleted.

Comment: A pity. I don't know why it drew the downvote - as far as I can tell, it was a perfectly legit question for the site (and one I'd still like to know the answer to). Was there something I missed?

Comment: No idea. You can flag it to request undeletion.